Unable to generate efficient assembly for reading data from binary stream using MSVC
I'm on a quest of figuring out if it's possible to write an endianness independent code for reading from binary streams with the following qualities:

Does not depend on host's endianness (i.e. the code should not try to determine local endianness via ifdefs or some other means). Obviously, endianness of source data has to be known.
Preferably the code should be C17 standard compliant, but widely adopted implementation defined behavior is good enough. No type punning, no violations of strict aliasing and pointer alignment rules.
Modern compilers should produce reasonably efficient instructions, somewhat close to mov or mov+bswap.
Integer types representation can be assumed to be 2's complement.
Floating point numbers are IEEE 754 compliant and have the same endianness rules as integers.
Mixed endianness and platforms with flexible runtime endianness can be ignored.

To simplify things, I'll only consider 32-bit types.
Integers.
int32_t read_i32_from_le(uint8_t* data)
{
    int32_t r = ((uint32_t)data[0] << 0) | 
                ((uint32_t)data[1] << 8) | 
                ((uint32_t)data[2] << 16) | 
                ((uint32_t)data[3] << 24);
    return r;
}

uint32_t read_u32_from_le(uint8_t* data)
{
    uint32_t r = ((uint32_t)data[0] << 0) |
                 ((uint32_t)data[1] << 8) | 
                 ((uint32_t)data[2] << 16) | 
                 ((uint32_t)data[3] << 24);
    return r;
}

int32_t read_i32_from_be(uint8_t* data)
{
    int32_t r = ((uint32_t)data[3] << 0) | 
                ((uint32_t)data[2] << 8) | 
                ((uint32_t)data[1] << 16) | 
                ((uint32_t)data[0] << 24);
    return r;
}

uint32_t read_u32_from_be(uint8_t* data)
{
    uint32_t r = ((uint32_t)data[3] << 0) |
                 ((uint32_t)data[2] << 8) | 
                 ((uint32_t)data[1] << 16) | 
                 ((uint32_t)data[0] << 24);
    return r;
}

This code mostly conforms to the aforementioned rules. It does contain implementation defined behavior (assignment  from uint32_t to int32_t), but, as stated previously, it's acceptable.
Unfortunately, it fails on the efficiency side of things. Or more specifically, it's MSVC that does the failing (godbolt):
read_i32_from_le PROC                             ; COMDAT
        movzx   edx, BYTE PTR [rcx+2]
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rcx+3]
        shl     eax, 8
        or      eax, edx
        movzx   edx, BYTE PTR [rcx+1]
        movzx   ecx, BYTE PTR [rcx]
        shl     eax, 8
        or      eax, edx
        shl     eax, 8
        or      eax, ecx
        ret     0

Floats.
To read floats in endianness independent manner we can reuse read_u32_* routines:
float read_f32_from_le(uint8_t* data)
{
    uint32_t bits = read_u32_from_le(data);
    float r;
    memcpy(&r, &bits, 4);
    return r;
}

Unsurprisingly, MSVC still struggles to generate reasonable instructions (godbolt):
read_f32_from_le PROC                             ; COMDAT
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rcx+2]
        movzx   edx, BYTE PTR [rcx+3]
        shl     edx, 8
        or      edx, eax
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rcx+1]
        shl     edx, 8
        or      edx, eax
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR [rcx]
        shl     edx, 8
        or      edx, eax
        mov     DWORD PTR r$[rsp], edx
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR r$[rsp]
        ret     0

Questions.

Is there some other way to achieve the desired result?
Is this a compiler bug, and should I file it with MSVC?


MSVC does not support: C17, C11, C99. So if ISO compliance is important to you, stay away from it.

@Lundin that's not true: MSVC has supported C11 and C17 Standard since 2020

@phuclv No. Lying in a blog doesn't make the compiler conforming - actually making changes to the compiler's functionality so that it behaves in accordance with ISO 9899 is what makes it conforming. Feel free to try printf("Here is %d good reason to use this compiler", __STDC__); on your ISO/IEC 9899/AMD1:1995 or later C compiler. Works with any garage trash compiler out there except one. Can you guess which one? And no /Za won't work because that's strict C89 mode.

No, ISO compliance is not that important; I specified the version just for completeness' sake. I'm more interested in an efficient solution across multiple compilers and avoiding UB.

@PavelT. Well this is quite obviously a missed optimization issue in MSVC, it seems unaware of the x86 BSWAP. Maybe there's some x86 target specification option that will help - I tried a few but no luck, but then I'm very far from an expert on this particular compiler.
